# How to securely store password for external API in a database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails application that will require a user to login. The application will also need to store a login and password for the user to access resources for an external API. I am using `bcrypt-ruby` for my application login, but I am not sure of the best way to store a username and password for an external site. I could use some advice on how to do this best.

Is it possible to extend the `has_secure_password` method for both logins (login for my application, and the external API)?

Comment: I'd look into Devise's Token Authenticatable Module https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Answer (score 0):

If you need to authenticate users from a third party website, and you have control over the third party website, probably the best protocol to work with nowdays is [oauth](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-31).

Now, in order to store the user and password of the users, encrypting the user/password in a hard protocol to encryption algorithm, like bcrypt, is good enough, if someone by some way is able to get the bcrypt string, he will be able to authentify into your website, but not on the third party website because he won't be able to decipher the user/pass encrypted with bcrypt.

Comment: if I had control of the thrid party site, would I refer to it as a third party?  :)